# MySQL Database Import Procedure

Tags: mysql, database

I'm doing a job that involves importing products from a CSV file into a WooCommerce site that is already live.  I was wondering if there are any precautionary steps that I need to take before executing a script that modifies the database like that.

My assumption would be to take a backup of the database, temporarily put the site offline, execute the script, then put the site back online.  Is there anything else that I should be doing?

Answer (score 2):

I would just make a backup of the database because although nothing would get deleted if stuff gets inserted wrong it is easier to just delete everything and insert both files than trying to go through everything and delete the newly imported data. Other than that I think you do not need to temporarily take down your website; that script should be finished very quickly assuming it is not inserting hundreds of thousands of rows. But if you want to take it down for a while just in-case that is completely based of whichever you would prefer (not necessary). The most important thing is to just make sure your import method is correct before your execution. Other than those few things you should be all set. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

With something like eCommerce I would say take a full backup (so not just databases), and restore them somewhere, like a sub domain, check everything is working, then push that live. You may have to take a copy of customer order's say before you restore and match the two up?

Answer (score 0):

That would be enough as far as I know. As @Devon Bernad said, you don't have to put offline unless you have something to do with front end. Best of luck. :)